# Can you define custom command line commands in your application?

Tags: android, .net

Can I create a program in .NET with different functionalities and commands which I can execute through the command line? (What I want is to develop a console application I can deploy to my android phone with certain functions and commands and I wanna be able to execute these commands through the command line of android)

Also can i deploy .NET console applications with no gui on to my mobile and run in as i would exactly on my laptop? or would it need to be configured differently for mobile?

Comment: Yes, an Android app can execute custom commands; see https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]). I'm not sure what you're asking in regard to .NET.

Comment: @larsH Thanks and i forgot to add the other part of the question - edited it now

Comment: https://github.com/Thraka/SadConsole I assume you need to write a full screen app and simulate the terminal, which is very common in games. You cannot use .NET console application types, as there is simply no such thing on mobile.

Comment: @LexLi Wouldn't .NET applications run on an android mobile? I dont see why it can't. Correct me if i'm wrong but I was told that mobile apps built using Xamarin runs .NET for it's backend functions - so assuming my app doesn't have a front end and everything runs via command prompt - shouldn't a .NET application be able to compile and run on my android mobile? I'm pretty new to .NET so i might be mixing up concepts here

Comment: I won't be able to teach you everything about Xamarin, but your current understanding is a little far from the truth. When I said "no such thing on mobile", I meant it literally, as iOS and Android do not support typical console applications you know of on desktop machines. Luckily frameworks like SadConsole can emulate the same experience good enough. SadConsole runs upon MonoGame, which in turn can ship upon Xamarin as a mobile app. It is tricky to fully understand the application model, but the keywords I provided should be enough for you to Google further. Other approaches do exist.